# How to Have video recording and downloading using v2.2(version of opentok)

Tags: javascript, webrtc, videochat, opentok, tokbox

**How to include video recording and downloading in this code, My previous query in this question was solved successfully but now I need to have archiving feature in this solution.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="myPublisherDiv"></div>
      <div id="subscriberBucket"></div>

      <script src="https://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/opentok.min.js" ></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

        var apiKey = "<YOUR API KEY>";
        var sessionId = "<YOUR SESSION ID>";
        var token = "<YOUR SESSION ID'S TOKEN>";

        session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);

      session.connect(token, function (err) {
              if (!err) {
                  session.publish("myPublisherDiv", { mirror: false });
              }
          });
          session.on({
              "streamCreated": function (event) {
                  session.subscribe(event.stream,  "subscriberBucket", { width: 600, height: 450 }, { insertMode: "append" });
              }
          });

      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**And please mention in yur answer if anything is wrong or not in this line**

```
 session.on({
              "streamCreated": function (event) {
                  session.subscribe(event.stream,  "subscriberBucket", { width: 600, height: 450 }, { insertMode: "append" });
```

Comment: Can you include your source code as well?

Comment: Please see the edits, there are some code for timer and ajax code for some data entry in my database, so ignore them

Comment: on clicking mic or audio icon , it looks like this page is attempting to execute some code or is requesting something to `static.opentok.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested on another [OpenTok app](https://opentokrtc.com) and clicked on mute and sound icons but could not reproduce what you are seeing.
I then created a new very simple group video chat app, clicked on mute and sound icons and I also could not reproduce what you are seeing.

I will paste in my group video chat app, you can start from this and slowly add in your own code part by part. Then you will be able to see what is causing your session to disconnect. Here is my simple group video chat app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myPublisherDiv"></div>
  <div id="subscriberBucket"></div>

  <script src="https://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/opentok.min.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var apiKey = "<YOUR API KEY>";
    var sessionId = "<YOUR SESSION ID>";
    var token = "<YOUR SESSION ID'S TOKEN>";

    session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);

    session.connect(token, function(err){
        if( !err ){
          session.publish("myPublisherDiv");
        }
    });
    session.on({
        "streamCreated": function(event){
          session.subscribe( event.stream, "subscriberBucket", {insertMode: "append"} );
        }
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see the edits, Your solution worked, and there is no problem on clicking mic or audio button, but now I need to have recording/archiving feature also, with download option, Please see the edits